# Nginx - show a specific page if IP is not whitelisted

Tags: nginx

I want to have a whitelist of IPs, and if your IP is not on the list then it serves `comingsoon.html` to you.

How can I achieve this?

At the moment I have the whitelist set up, but I don't know how to serve a specific page to IPs that aren't on the whitelist

This is what I have at the moment for my server block:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/public;
        index index.php;

        server_name example.dev 192.168.33.10;

        error_page 404 /404.php;

        location / {
        allow 10.0.1.26;
        deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `error_page` directive for `403 Forbidden`:

```
error_page 403 /comingsoon.html;
```

If you also want to change the response code to `200 OK`:

```
error_page 403 =200 /comingsoon.html;
```

Reference: [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

Comment: I had to add `location = /comingsoon.html {}` above the whitelist for this to work since access to comingsoon.html was also being denied.